# How to send SMS in Amazon SNS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have a free amazon account (Basic plan) and want to send SMS as described here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html#sms_publish_console
but there is no "In the navigation pane, choose Text messaging (SMS)".
Is this because of plan restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMS option for AWS SNS works only in US East Region. Change your AWS region from the region dropdown on top right and you will see that SMS option. Check screenshot below

[image]